# Optaplanner ConstraintStreams

Tags: java, optaplanner

I'm struggling with "higher-level" ConstraintStreams (bi, tri ..). In the Optaplanner Userguide the most simple cases are shown and I understand them. Also with the examples I was able to groupBy - sum a BiConstraintStream.
Now I have a TriConstraintStream and facing problems. Does anyone know a good source of information to understand the ConstraintStreams better?

My case: The problem structure is very similar to the transportation problem. I have nodes and edges and want to calculate the quantity of the edges.

My main problem fact is:

```
class Node{
   UUID id;
   int itemsInInventory;
   ...
}
```

And the planning entity:

```
@PlanningEntity
class Edge{
   Node from;
   Node to; 
   @PlanningVariable
   int itemsTransported;

   getFromId(){return from.getId()}
   getToId(){return to.getId()}

}
```

I want to join the Edges two times into the nodes and then groupBy them do have an Object like `(Node, Sum(to), Sum(from))`

The currentcode of the constraint is:

```
public Constraint minimizeShortage(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.fromUnfiltered(Node.class)
            .join(Edge.class,
                    equal(Node::getId, Edge::getFromId))
            .join(Edge.class,
                    equal((node, edge) -> node.getId(), Edge::getToId))
            groupBy(...)
}
```

For the BiConstraintStream (using only the fromNode or toNode) the groupBy would be              `.groupBy((node, edge) -> node, sum((node, edge) -> edge.getItemsTransported()))` but I don't get the TriConstraintStream after the second join to work.

Answer (score 2):

I will take the code from the previous answer as the starting point for mine:

```
public Constraint minimizeShortage(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.fromUnfiltered(Node.class)
        .join(Edge.class,
                equal(Node::getId, Edge::getFromId))
        .groupBy((node, edgeFrom) -> node,
                sum((node, tsaO) -> edgeFrom.transportedItems()))
        .join(Edge.class,
                equal((node, edge) -> node.getId(), Edge::getToId))
        .groupBy((node, edgeFrom, edgeTo) -> node,
                (node, edgeFrom, edgeTo) -> qtO,
                sum((node, qtO, edgeTo) -> edgeTo.transportedItems()))
        ...
}
```

This code is unlikely to perform well, as `groupBy()` is expensive and chaining them makes the problem gradually worse. Let's see if we can do the same thing with just one `groupBy()`:

```
public Constraint minimizeShortage(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.fromUnfiltered(Node.class)
        .join(Edge.class,
                equal(Node::getId, Edge::getFromId))
        .join(Edge.class,
                equal((node, edge) -> node.getId(), Edge::getToId))
        .groupBy((node, edgeFrom, edgeTo) -> node,
                sum((node, edgeFrom, edgeTo) -> edgeFrom.transportedItems()),
                sum((node, edgeFrom, edgeTo) -> edgeTo.transportedItems())
        ...
}
```

Let's discuss this a bit more. This particular `groupBy()` overload consists of two parts: the key mapping and the collectors.

The key mapping  splits the triples into groups - in this case (`(node, edgeFrom, edgeTo) -> node`) all the triples with the same `node` will fall into the same group.

Each collector then produces a result of applying a given operation (`sum` in this case) on each such group of triples. We use two collectors here, one which sums up items transported in `edgeFrom`, and the other does the same for `edgeTo`. And both of those collectors only apply to edges which share the same `node` - as guaranteed by the aforementioned key mapping.

As a side note, when developing non-trivial constraints like this, I absolutely recommend using [Constraint Verifier](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#constraintStreamsTesting) to model some of the typical outcomes and see if the constraint behaves as expected.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. Your suggestion was exactly what I initially tried to build. But your solution does not work and result in a syntax error. "Cannot resolve method 'transportedItems()' in 'Object'". The compiler does not understand, that edgeTo is from class Edge

Comment: I found another failure, the inner join is also a problem. After. the first join I get a list if stations which are suppliers ("nodeFrom"). in the nodes. I kick all nodes without edges and which have in the nodeTo attribute. After the second join I get a list of all stations which are suppliers AND in another node demanders. So I kick all nodes which are not both. What I supposed to do was to have a result like "Node, EdgeWhereNodeFrom, EdgeWhereNodeTo" where Edge is the list of all possible edges and EdgeWhereNodeFrom and EdgeWhereNodeTo are the edges where the node is present.

Comment: These fluent APIs can sometimes be tricky when it comes to the compiler. If you're getting type errors, it can often be because something else in the stream is wrong and compiler can not resolve the fluent call chain as a whole. As far as I know, there is nothing wrong with my code sample, so my guess is that there is something wrong in the part that says "..." which we can not see here.

Comment: As far as your second join-related comment is concerned, I suggest we bring that discussion to the other question you asked for that.

Comment: Are you sure? The groupby is closed after that and then a simple penalize follows (no logic for test reasons, just access the itemsInventory of the node). I tried several things. Using just one sum(..) it works fine, but at the moment I add the comma to do the second sum(,...) the error comes.

Comment: Only one way to find out. Please submit your code in a way that I can run through the compiler, and I can take a look at what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem. The solution was to use the syntax below and especially to not sum up in one groupBy. I had to split the summing into two groupBys and calculate it in the following order: Join1 - groupBy1 - join2 - groupBy2.

```
public Constraint minimizeShortage(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return     constraintFactory.fromUnfiltered(Node.class)
            .join(Edge.class,
                    equal(Node::getId, Edge::getFromId))
            .groupBy((node, edgeFrom) -> node,
                    sum((node, tsaO) -> edgeFrom.transportedItems()))
            .join(Edge.class,
                    equal((node, edge) -> node.getId(), Edge::getToId))
            .groupBy((node, edgeFrom, edgeTo) -> node,
                    (node, edgeFrom, edgeTo) -> qtO,
                    sum((node, qtO, edgeTo) -> edgeTo.transportedItems()))
            ...
}
```

Comment: Even though this may do what you want it to (and I wholeheartedly recommend that you verify that with Constraint Verifier (https://docs.optaplanner.org/8.5.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#constraintStreamsTesting)), it will not perform very well. Multiple groupby() in a single constraint are a good way to kill your score calculation counts. I will provide a different answer shortly.